# do i need to install motherboard and graphic card drivers..? if yes then how..?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon, motherboard

Right now I am windows user but I am thinking of using of ubuntu. So if I install ubuntu do I need to install motherboard and graphic card drivers like windows?
My motherboard is Gigabyte B75M-D3V and graphic card is Sapphire Radeon HD6450 (2GB)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to install "motherboard" drivers.

But you probably may want to install proprietary video drivers from System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain some facts about Linux:

- Linux is "Plug and Play" in 99% of the cases. Most drivers are present by default in the Linux kernel, and that means you'll rarely need to install any additional drivers (unlike in Windows). For example, if you buy a brand new flash drive you can be pretty sure that you'll connect it in your Linux box and it WILL work.
- The same happens with most hardware. Video cards/GPUs, wireless adapters, bluetooth cards... If you have extremely new hardware, prefer getting a newer Ubuntu version (current is 15.10). The kernel is more up-to-date and new hardware will probably be recognized. If you have older hardware, prefer a LTS version (current is 14.04), which comes with more stable packages and is usually very trusty (get it? Trusty Tahr?).
- Ubuntu comes with an application called "Additional drivers". You can use it to easily manage your hardware drivers. Ubuntu automatically selects the open source drivers for your GPU, for example, but you can install proprietary drivers to have better performance, if you want.